# $_SESSION array() with expiry time

Tags: php, arrays, session

so i found this [tutorial](http://spotlesswebdesign.com/blog.php?id=11) that creates a unique ID to prevent duplicate form submit, this is the script im using:

```
// start session
session_start();

// set page instance id
if (!isset($_SESSION['page_instance_ids'])) {
    $_SESSION['page_instance_ids'] = array();
}
$_SESSION['page_instance_ids'][] = uniqid('', true);

// form processing logic
$page_id_index = array_search($_POST['page_instance_id'], $_SESSION['page_instance_ids']);
if ($page_id_index !== false) {
    unset($_SESSION['page_instance_ids'][$page_id_index]);
    // do form processing

}
```

if i open the form in another tab this is the result:

```
["page_instance_ids"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "52cada0446c6a1.79120890"
    [1]=>
    string(23) "52cada0bb62bc0.91394639"
  }
```

at the end it recommends this:

Consider saving a timestamp with each page_instance_id in your session array, or limiting the session array to only the latest n values, so that you may clean out any old page instance ids that never got used to submit a form.

i have this code that unsets all sessions after X time:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
// last request was more than 30 minutes ago
session_unset(); // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

i would like to know if there is any way to UNSET independently each string from the array that was created... like it is recommended.

Comment: why are you creating new array? you can replace the existing one like `$_SESSION['page_instance_ids'][0]` or just `$_SESSION['page_instance_ids']`

Comment: @kumar_v The reason we keep the session page_instance_ids in an array instead of only storing the latest value, is in case the user has more than one window or tab open for our website. In that case, the latest served page may not be the next form to be submitted.

Comment: then you have to associate form id with session id.